# Remove characters between delimiter in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle database 18 c and Oracle Apex 22.

I have a string like this one:

```
'Hello this Marc ||www.stackoverflow.com|| welcome to our family'
```

I want to remove any character within this delimiter **||**

So the output should be:

```
'Hello this Marc welcome to our family'
```

Can anyone help with a regexp query that does that?

Comment: Removing everything between and including `||` results in `'Hello this Marc  welcome to our family'` (two spaces between `Marc` and `welcome`), not `'Hello this Marc welcome to our family'` (single space). Please explain why an extra character should be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you put it, combination of `substr` and `instr` functions returns that result:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Hello this Marc ||www.stackoverflow.com|| welcome to our family' from dual)
```

Query:

```
  3  select substr(col, 1, instr(col, '|') - 2) ||
  4         substr(col, instr(col, '|', 1, 4) + 1) as result
  5  from test;

RESULT
-------------------------------------
Hello this Marc welcome to our family

SQL>
```

Or, if you prefer regular expressions, remove everything between outmost pipe signs:

```
  3  select regexp_replace(col, ' \|.+\|') result
  4    from test;

RESULT
-------------------------------------
Hello this Marc welcome to our family

SQL>
```